# Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to parse fiscal year from a given date column to arrange data as per fiscal year and I am getting this error while running the same code with other .Rmd file i didnt get this error.

I used various options such as using anytime instead of lubridate, and supplying origin = "1970=01-01" the issue persists. Also, it seem the issue comes after i use the fiscal_year function. I am using windows 10 system with R studio R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11).

```
processed <- payments %>%
          mutate(scheduled_payment_date = mdy(scheduled_payment_date),
               due_date_month = month(scheduled_payment_date),
               due_date_year = year(scheduled_payment_date),
               adjustment = ifelse(due_date_month>=4,1,0),
               fiscal_year = year(due_date_year) + adjustment)
```

I expect the fiscal_year column to be created but instead I am getting the following error. The same code worked in my other.Rmd file.

> Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: Please add a reproducible example using `dput(payments)`.

Comment: structure(list(grant_status = c("Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed"), target_cash_amount = c(4291970, 
1746455, 2701209, 2701209, 248721, 3e+06, 3e+06, 3039750), scheduled_payment_date = c("3/31/2018", 
"8/25/2014", "11/14/2014", "4/28/2016", "7/15/2015", "11/30/2013", 
"12/30/2014", "1/1/2009")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L))

Comment: thanks Ronak, let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

payments %>%
   mutate(scheduled_payment_date = mdy(scheduled_payment_date),
          due_date_month = month(scheduled_payment_date),
          due_date_year = year(scheduled_payment_date), 
          adjustment = as.integer(due_date_month>=4),
          fiscal_year = due_date_year + adjustment)

#  grant_status target_cash_amount scheduled_payment_date due_date_month due_date_year adjustment fiscal_year
#  <chr>                     <dbl> <date>                          <dbl>         <dbl>      <int>       <dbl>
#1 Closed                  4291970 2018-03-31                          3          2018          0        2018
#2 Closed                  1746455 2014-08-25                          8          2014          1        2015
#3 Closed                  2701209 2014-11-14                         11          2014          1        2015
#4 Closed                  2701209 2016-04-28                          4          2016          1        2017
#5 Closed                   248721 2015-07-15                          7          2015          1        2016
#6 Closed                  3000000 2013-11-30                         11          2013          1        2014
#7 Closed                  3000000 2014-12-30                         12          2014          1        2015
#8 Closed                  3039750 2009-01-01                          1          2009          0        2009
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same :) `year` is expecting a date as input, and you were providing a number. Since you've already extracted the year in `due_date_year = year(scheduled_payment_date)`, you can just use the numeric value there.

Comment: excellent Ronak, I noted the silly mistake i was making in the last line of the code, also, the as.integer is much neater for deriving the fiscal year adjustment in this case.